# How to delete SKShapeNode in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I'm making a SpriteKit project where one game screen needs to allow the user to draw on the screen. I want to have a "delete all" button and an "undo" button. However, I can't find out how to delete a path anywhere online. Here's how I'm drawing my lines:

```
var pathToDraw:CGMutablePathRef!
var lineNode:SKShapeNode!

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

    pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, nil, touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y)

    lineNode = SKShapeNode()
    lineNode.path = pathToDraw
    lineNode.strokeColor = drawColor
    self.addChild(lineNode)
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, nil, touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y)
    lineNode.path = pathToDraw   
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {}
```

But now the problem is how can I delete them? I have tried `lineNode.removeFromParent()` but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track of the `SKShapeNodes` you draw on the screen in an array. First create a property `shapeNodes`

```
var shapeNodes : [SKShapeNode] = []
```

Add each `lineNode` to the `shapeNodes` in `touchesBegan`

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    //Your code
    shapeNodes.append(lineNode)
}
```

On pressing delete all button you loop through the shapeNodes array and remove them one by one.

```
func deleteAllShapeNodes() {

    for node in shapeNodes
    {
        node.removeFromParent()
    }
    shapeNodes.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
}
```

For undo, you just have to delete the last node in the `shapeNodes` array.

```
 func undo() {
    shapeNodes.last?.removeFromParent()
    shapeNodes.removeLast()
 }
```

Comment: Thanks rakeshbs this makes alot of sense! I got the delete all button to work but the undo part is not working, nothing happens when I try to remove the last item...I will keep working and find something.

Answer (score 0):

But `lineNode.removeFromParent()` does work--perhaps you're not actually calling it? Here, I'm doing it in your `touchesEnded(touches:withEvent:)` method, but you can call this from anywhere you'd like:

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    lineNode.removeFromParent()
    lineNode = SKShapeNode()
}
```

Comment: That does work if you use it in touchesEnded, but only if it is called after you draw every single line. If you draw several lines and try to call this later, nothing happens.